# Insert div with insert() prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a problem with insert function of prototype. I have a div in HTML with 'main' id. In my script I use prototype to insert a new div ('container') inside 'main' div. But now I want to insert another div in 'container' div but I can't. The code is this:

```
    var container;
    var wordsDiv;

    function build(){
       container = new Element('div');
       wordsDiv = new Element('div');

       $('main').insert(container);
       container.insert(wordsDiv);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you have [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/9fnYW/). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JamesAllardice I don't know what happen! The code is the same of your link, the problem is that the second div which I want to insert in 'container' doesn't insert.

Comment: @JamesAllardice now works!!! But I don't know what was the problem. I had some comments in the middle of the code, maybe was this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var container;
var wordsDiv;

function build(){
   container = new Element('div');
   wordsDiv = new Element('div');

   $('main').insert(container);
   $(container).insert(wordsDiv);
}
```

Comment: This won't make a difference. `container` is already a Prototype-extended element. The `$` function will simply return it as it is.

Comment: See my comment on the question and the fiddle I've linked to - the OPs code should work fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `insert()`s out of order

```
var container;
var wordsDiv;

function build(){
   container = new Element('div');
   wordsDiv = new Element('div');

   container.insert(wordsDiv);
   $('main').insert(container);
}
```

I've had the problem you are describing before where if you dont completely build the element before it is inserted into the DOM you can't do any more manipulations on the element unless you reference it by id or class.

I'm not sure what browsers it has happened on but as a rule of thumb I try and build my elements and add observers to the elements if need be before inserting into the DOM.